# What does gpg error code 2(GPG_ERR_UNKNOWN_PACKET) mean?

Tags: gpg, exit-status

I am tasked to explain the variation of gpg errors that happened in one of my batch script. Currently when I perform gpg decrypt for a specified file it returns 2. The problem with this is when I search the form, it shows that the file has been decrypted properly but the error code is causing the script to stop because it only assumed that 0 is the only success value.

```
gpg -o XXX --decrypt XXX.gpg
RETVAL=$?
if [ RETVAL -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

I searched the net and found the header list for gpg. It defines error 2 as Unknown Packet.

http://www.gnu-darwin.org/www001/src/ports/security/libgpg-error/work/libgpg-error-1.5/src/err-codes.h.in

The normal error text being displayed is [gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=14)].
What exactly does the unknown packet mean? I am trying to search any documents on understanding the error codes. After showing all the verbose information using the [-vv] option. I compared the resulting gpg file decryption with a file that returns 0 code.
The only thing I noticed is the byte of the key is different.

The decryption of the gpg that is error free have the following log:

```
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 16, keyid <16-hexdigit>
    data    1023 bits
    data    1024 bits
```

The decryption of the gpg causing error have the following log:

```
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 16, keyid <16-hexdigit>
    data    1022 bits
    data    1022 bits
```

What does this mean? why can it still be decrypted properly even if the key bit is not the same? Note that the key-id and passphrase used to decrypt the two file are the same. Also, does anyone know any detailed resource on explaining the error of gpg.

Answer (score 7):

Largely used GPF codes are of three types :

1. 0 is success (all other values indicate a failure).
2. 2 is usually used for unxpected errors.
3. 1 for things like a BAD signature.

The proper way to identify an error is by interpreting the output of `--status-fd <file descriptor>` or `--status-file <filename>`.

Now for the particular Question that you are using, there might be two reasons :

1. GPG is asking whether you want to continue on with the encryption using an unsigned key. Since no user can input Y it produces an error.

To fix this provide the following switches :

```
    --yes and --always-trust
```

2. It may also be a permission problem. gpg is trying to access a directory that it can't have access to, so it fails with a fatal error. (error code 2)

You can fix that by specifying a homedir directive with a directory writable by gpg. Like this:

```
   $cmd = "/usr/bin/gpg -a --recipient $to -e -o $outfile $infile --homedir /path/to/dir";
```

Information from man gpg:

```
   --homedir directory
   Set the name of the home directory to directory

    If this option is not used it defaults to "~/.gnupg". It does not make sense to    use     this in a options file. This also overrides the environment variable $GNUPGHOME.
```

You can also use this [link](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2008-January/032410.html) to know more about this one.

Comment: The problem is not because the gpg is asking whether to continue decryption using unsigned key. Also, the gpg file does decrypt the file, the output file is produced but I am not sure of the validity of the file. As for the home directory, I checked the access rights and there is no problem. By the way how do you add --status-fd?

Answer (score 1):

One way of using the status-fd in linux is as follows:

```
GPG="${PGP_LOCATION}gpg --status-fd 2 --passphrase-fd 0 --no-verbose --batch --output ${OUTPUT} --decrypt ${DOUTPUT}"
echo "GPG:${GPG}"
${GPG} 2>&1 >> ${STATUS} < ${PASSFILE}
```

Note that all the shell variables are set up to point to the right values. Output from gpg is captured in the `${STATUS}`  ( a file ) ...